# Fundamental groups and covering spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application of Seifert-van Kampen Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93243/application-of-seifert-van-kampen-theorem)

Let $X$ be as in the following figure. What is the first fundamental group, $\Pi_1 (X)$, of $X$? What are the covering spaces of $X$?

[image: Topological space $X$]

Comment: Is this homework? Also, what did you try?